# How to insert Latin accent inside lstlisting -

Tags: listings, verbatim, algorithms, accents

Could you please help me find a way to insert Latin accents in the lstlistings environment? I've tried the direct way and also the indirect way, i.e using ç and \c{c}. However, when using ç, this error appers:

Package inpuntec Error: Unicode char ...\lst@EC ... (U+9EA7)(inpuntec) not set up for use with LaTeX.

Replacing the ç for the \c{c} gets rid of the error, but when the pdf is generated, the output is not converted to ç, but instead, it stays as \c{c}.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[literate={ç}{{\c{c}}}1]
ç
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's probably easier to just use LuaLaTeX and the following setup.  Note also how `ç` is actually a single character here ([U+00E7 LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e7/index.htm) to be precise).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
ç
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]